# Increase the performance of asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, telerik

We have one page which is about 300 KB after compression of viewstate. It's loading very slow. We are using telerik tabstrip. There are 8 user controls being loaded for this tab. Is there anyway we can improve the performance of this page? Any ideas please.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, don't enable viewstate is one approach.  Alternatively, you could load each tab on demand, so when the tab is clicked, cause a postback, and show that tab's content (which could be wrapped in a RadAjaxPanel from Telerik).

Lastly, Telerik has a rich web service model; bind the information to the UI via web services when the tab is clicked.  This is something we had to do and it worked out very well performance-wise.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Let me try your suggestions.

Comment: Hi Brian, We have a common update button for all the tabs. How does it work if we use RadAjaxPanel? Please let me know. Also do you have any example using rich web service model?

Comment: demos.telerik.com has plenty of examples.  As with the UpdatePanel, any control refreshes the RadAjaxPanel (but only that panel, not all panels) and its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can try page level caching - [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bh14hk.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the RadTabStrip itself you could also potentially look into using the Load-on-Demand feature as well, found on [this demo page](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/examples/applicationscenarios/loadondemand/defaultcs.aspx).

As for overall page efficiency if you are using the Telerik RadControls already you could look into using the RadAjax control; particularly the RadAjaxManager. This will allow you set up partial postbacks and get a more efficient page. A demo of this can be found [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajax/examples/manager/firstlook/defaultcs.aspx).

Comment: I would like to save the information from these tabs at once.Does Load-on-Demand works in my case?

Comment: Load-on-demand would only allow you to grab information from the particular tabs that have been viewed by the user, since they are the only ones that have been loaded. However, a common case in terms of saving items from these tabs would be that if the user has not accessed the tab then the already stored information could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Our of the box use of the telerik tab control is not efficient. Each tab not in use STILL GETS put through the page lifecycle. There isn't anything that you can do about that out of the box, but with a little extra configuration you can gain some efficiency.

For the tab that is to be shown, you can dynamically `LoadControl` for the UserControl that is to be shown on the selected tab.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled RADCOMPRESSION ?

http://www.telerikwatch.com/2009/01/optimization-tips-radcompression-module.html

Answer (score 0):

You could always not use telerik!  It creates such a heavy internal dependence on itself with bloated, unnecessarily complex features it makes me want to vomit.  Do it yourself for best results...MVC rocks!  Or just follow the answers above and get ready for lots of trial and error... :sadface: